# how to remove special characters at the beginning / end (first/last) of a string in swift 4

Tags: swift, string, swift4

how to remove special characters at the beginning/end of a string in swift 4

For example,

```
let myString = "abcde."
```

**IF** I want to remove special characters from the **end** of **myString** like `.` then it returns to me `abcde`

**OR**, if I want to remove `e.` at the end, it will return `abcd`.

**AND**, if I put something wrong like `de`, it will return the **original** string `abcde.`

Removing special characters at the **beginning** is the similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you should do to meet the requirement in the question is to make an `extension` of `String`

```
extension String {
    // remove the end
    func removeTheSpecialCharAtLast(char: String) -> String {
        if hasSuffix(char){
            return String(dropLast(char.count))
        }
        return self
    }

    // remove the beginning
    func removeTheSpecialCharAtFirst(char: String) -> String {
        if hasPrefix(char){
            return String(dropFirst(char.count))
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

And, I've made a test to remove chars at the end. To remove chars at the beginning is similar

```
    let myString = "abcde."
    let op1 = myString.removeTheSpecialCharAtLast(char: "cd")
    let op2 = myString.removeTheSpecialCharAtLast(char: ".")
    let op3 = myString.removeTheSpecialCharAtLast(char: "de")
    let op4 = myString.removeTheSpecialCharAtLast(char: "de.")
    print(op1)   //abcde.
    print(op2)   //abcde
    print(op3)   //abcde.
    print(op4)   //abc
```